# The state of the application is not updated instantly in the code via props in React, MobX

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, mobx, mobx-react

If I have such a code

```
<button onClick = {()=>{
store.increment()
console.log(store.count)
}
}>{store.count}</button>
```

Then when you click on the button, the counter will be updated, and the counter will already be updated in the console.
But if you create a Counter component that will accept the quantity and callback, the state will be asynchronous

```
<Counter count = {store.count} increment = {store.increment}/>
```

How can I make sure that the state in the console is already updated. Without the didUpdate method and the update hook if possible

codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-counter-example-forked-v3qcrw?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you create minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/? Otherwise it's quite hard to guess what is the problem here with such little amount of info.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-counter-example-forked-v3qcrw?file=/src/index.js. I dont know why state in this case is not updated visually. I know that if i pass only appState as props it will work, but in my case i need to pass only count and only increment method to component

Comment: @Danila I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: don't use outdated library versions. Update them to latest.

Second: change `observable` api to `makeAutoObservable`, remove extra `actions`.

And third: wrap every component that uses observable values into `observer` HOC. In your example you wrapped `Counter`, but Counter actually does not use any observable values, it only gets `appState.count` as a prop which will be a primitive value when you reference it. And then you pass Counter directly to ReactDOM.render, that won't work.

I've wrapped it with `App` component:

```
const App = observer(() => {
  return <Counter count={appState.count} increment={appState.incCounter} />;
});
```

Here is [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-71237541-66des6?file=/src/index.js:417-526) with working code

Comment: thanks, i little bit modified code. https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-71237541-forked-buleqy?file=/src/index.js. Why i am getting in console not updated instantly value. If i will do it without props, but directly accessing in store it will update instantly in console. What i should do, that console will display instantly updated value

Comment: You can either reference `appState.count` directly (but then it does not make sense that count is passed as prop) or you can for example return new value from the action and log it. It's not MobX limitation, it's just how Javascript closures work, you can rewrite same code with `useState` and it would behave the same. Please mark the question as accepted if it solved your problem